# Android Activity contentView size

Tags: java, android, android-activity

[image: Sample]

There are many question if you search.
The answers are telling the screen width / height. NOT that needed!

**I need the available space for the image view: the car with white background. How to get it?**

I don't need the top decoration bar, neither the bottom / right menu bar neither the whole screen size wich include the time, battery.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SVGImageView svgImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        svgImageView = new SVGImageView(this);
        svgImageView.setImageAsset("my.svg");

        // Set the ImageView as the content view for the Activity
        setContentView(svgImageView);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        int w = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        int h = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
        Log.d("DisplayMetrics","w2:"+w+", h2:"+h);// 0 and 0
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        //int bottom = svgImageView.getBottom();

        int w = svgImageView.getWidth();//0
        int h = svgImageView.getHeight();//0

        Log.d("DisplayMetrics", "width: "+width+ ", height:"+height+", w:"+w+", h:"+h);
        // landscape: 1280 x 752.  Real 1280x700
        // portrait: 800 x 1232. Real 800x1177


    }
```

SVGImageView is a child of ImageView more about SVG [Here](http://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) if anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer should give the same amount of Widh and height than this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    svgImageView = new SVGImageView(this){

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int canvasH = canvas.getHeight();
            int canvasW = canvas.getWidth();
            Log.d("DisplayMetrics", "canvasW:"+canvasW + ", canvasH: "+canvasH);// Portrait 800 x 1176,  Landscape 1280 x 696,                  
        }
```

I am checking the [Activity source](http://gitorious.org/rowboat/frameworks-base/source/aa93bcd62482719c146a411008e1eac94135b6a4:core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

```
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getWindow().setContentView(view);
}
```

I think the mWindow will have the required data. The question is **When** and **how** to get it?

Unfortunately that is an [abstract method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/view/Window.java#Window.setContentView%28android.view.View%29):

```
public abstract void setContentView(View view);
```

But overriding the `onSizeChanged` at new SVGImageView(this) I will have the numbers properly there.

[PhoneWindow](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java) is the implementation for me, now:

```
// This is the top-level view of the window, containing the window decor.
private DecorView mDecor;

// This is the view in which the window contents are placed. It is either
// mDecor itself, or a child of mDecor where the contents go.
private ViewGroup mContentParent;


private final class DecorView extends FrameLayout implements RootViewSurfaceTaker
```

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

My call log:

```
myActivity.onPostResume()
myContentView.onSizeChanged()
myContentView.onDraw();
```

=> need to subscribe to layout listener or override top component `onSizeChanged`